# Selecting filename from a logs path

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting. I need to redirect a filename from the below logpath to another file. How can this be achieved using sed command.

/home/path/logs/filename_script/_SUCCESS.

I need to redirect the filename from the above path(/home/path/logs/filename_script/_SUCCESS). Please help.

Comment: Do you mean that on success full completion of a script `/home/path/logs/**filename**_script` you want to move the contents to `/home/path/logs/**filename**_script/_SUCCESS`? Or you Want to create a file `/home/path/logs/**filename**_script/_SUCCESS` and put some content there?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right :

```
f='/home/path/logs/filename_script/_SUCCESS' 
echo "$f" | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | tee another_file
```

Comment: Apologies! Have edited my original question. can you please help me out?

Comment: Hey gilles! Thanks for your response. But I need to redirect filename from the /home/path/logs/**filename**_script/_SUCCESS path

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can try this:

```
cd /home/path/logs/filename_script/_SUCCESS
ls -1 > <another file>
```

The foregoing will list all of the filenames in ../_SUCESS path and redirect it to the other file. Take note that -1 option will arrange the file in sequence. If you want to just redirect single filename, then you can hardcode it or use wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not very efficient but simple.

```
 basename $(dirname "/home/path/logs/filename_script/_SUCCESS" )
 filename_script
```

to redirect it into any file.

```
basename $(dirname "/home/path/logs/filename_script/_SUCCESS" ) > to_new_file
```